# how to broadcast live streaming in android mobile app using satellite connection

Tags: android, live-streaming, satellite

I have my own TV Channel with asia satellite. I want to watch TV channel in my android mobile app. I have provided all possible connection parameters to satellite.

What I have searched so far like I have to use a decoder which will connect to the satellite and then be using any live streaming site it will make a live streaming to the server then in my android mobile app, I can connect to server for live streaming.

Can anyone know how I can watch my TV Channel in my android mobile app using satellite connection?

here are the satellite connection parameters.
 Asia Sat 7 (105.5)
 Frequency 3700 MHz
 Symbol Rate 4167 MS/s
 FEC 5/6
 Polarization Vertical
 Format DVB S-PAL Mpeg2
 Services ID Praise TV

thanks

Answer (score 0):

TV satellites (and the majority of Geostationary satellites) broadcast using radio waves in different bands like C-BAND and KU-BAND, in order to receive from the satellite, you need a dish to gather radio waves and direct them to the receiver and then you need a decoder to lets say convert that data into and image and sound for the TV to view it.

Now if you want to view the channel from your mobile phone, you will need a way to receive the data and send it as a stream to you mobile, because your mobile CANT read the data sent my the satellite on its own.

So the practical solution is to use one of the streaming services or research a satellite receiver that broadcasts the channel into the network.